# Loop into html elements to decide the side of each

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I am on a chat app project, I made a code that if the user is not me the bubble chat of that user will be at the left side, and if the user is me, the bubble chat if me will be at the right place.

The code works, but it only works for the firts bubble chat, I want it to work for every bubble chats that are in there, ALSO, my code generate the bubble chats, so there is not a number of bubble chats defined

here is my code:
JS

```
  window.onload = function() {
  var users = $("#user").text()
  var side = "msg right-msg";
  var chats = $("#side");
  var box = $(".msger-chat");

  for (chats in box) {
    if (users != me) {
    var side = "msg left-msg";
    };
    document.getElementById("side").className = document.getElementById("side").className.replace( 
    /(?:^|\s)msg right-msg(?!\S)/g , side)

    console.log(users);
  }

}
```

Bubble chats html code:

```
     <div class="msg right-msg" id="side">
      <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: 
        url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145867.svg)"></div>

      <div class="msg-bubble">
          <div class="msg-info">
          <div class="msg-info-name" id="user">{{ chat.user }}</div>
          <div class="msg-info-time"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="msg-text" id="buttom">{{ chat.message }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I think the solution might be making a For loop, I did that but that doesn't work, it still change the side of only one bubble chat.

Answer (score 0):

I think the for loop is only working with the first one because you are using `getElementById` and should be getting it by a class name.

Comment: that doesn't work, it still changing the side of the firts one

Comment: is there any other solution?